# Что такое умклайдет?))

Tags: литература

Все сокращения и аббревиатуры в "Понедельник начинается в субботу" понятны: Изнакурнож, НИИЧАВО, и только неясным остается название волшебной палочки - умклайдет. Что это за слово? Какое-то сокращение или Стругацкие просто придумали его?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//---------
Что такое "умклайдет"?

Волшебная палочка из "Понедельник начинается в субботу" братьев Стругацких.

С сайта Стругацких (http://www.rusf.ru/abs/):

OFF-LINE интервью с Борисом Стругацким
Май 1999

... Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему "умклайдет" из повести-сказки "Понедельник начинается в субботу" и сценария "Чародеи" был назван именно так, а не иначе?

```
Yuri Zubakin 2:5010/67.20@FIDOnet.org  
Россия - 05/27/99 21:22:24 MSK
```

Hасколько я помню, название это возникло так: я взял немецко-русский словарь, раскрыл его наугад и наткнулся на слово umkleiden. Звучание нам понравилось, мы поиграли этим словом так и сяк - образовался "умкляйдет". Hикакого смысла в это слово мы не вкладывали. (Umkleiden означает - "переодевать", а также "обивать, обтягивать" и "окружать".)
//-----------

[Что такое "умклайдет"? | xsuseless.narod.ru](http://xsuseless.narod.ru/Rubrics/Terms/u989.htm)